# How to create a trigger in PostgreSQL without delegating control to a function?

Tags: postgresql

I'm familiar with the method where the trigger is fired by a function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_function();
```

I would like to know if there is a way to now eliminate the need for the function.  Something like this doesn't seem to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.col1 = OLD.col1 + 1
END
```

The error I keep getting is: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"`

If I get rid of `BEGIN` and `END`, it says: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET"`

Other variations fail as well. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE mytable SET col1 = OLD.col1 + 1;
```

Can this be done now?  I'm currently using v9.4.

Comment: No, you always need to first create the trigger function.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE UPDATE`...?

Comment: @Politank-Z That's not valid syntax in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it, it simply isn't supported. That's why it isn't working.

You *must* use trigger functions in PostgreSQL. You can't just write some SQL in-line in the trigger.